# How to get the current text field value in controller using ng-change?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

here i want to get text field value in controller function evrytime i changed the text field

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" ng-model="viewItemData1.quantity" ng-change="changePrice($event.target.value);">

 $scope.changePrice = function(val)
  {
     console.log(val);
     alert(val); 
     alert(JSON.stringfy(console.log(val))); 


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a variable in the controller

```
$scope.val;
```

then in your html use ng-model

```
<input id="name" ng-model="val">
```

In this case you can simply:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" ng-model="viewItemData1.quantity" ng-change="changePrice();">

$scope.changePrice = function()
 {
 console.log($scope.viewItemData1.quantity);
 alert($scope.viewItemData1.quantity); 
 alert(JSON.stringfy(console.log($scope.viewItemData1.quantity))); 
 }
```

Comment: just now fixed and working fine

        $scope.changePrice = function(val)
   {
   
            var tprice=(val * $scope.viewItemData1.quantity); 
             $scope.viewItemData.tprice=tprice;
     }

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML `ng-model="viewItemData1.quantity"` will take care of data binding, you don't need `ng-change` method , So in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" ng-model="viewItemData1.quantity">
```

then in your controller, Set a $watch on your input field and do whatever you want to do when it changes:

```
$scope.$watch("viewItemData1.quantity", function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal );
      alert(newVal );
      // or do whatever you want to do.
  }
});
```

Comment: $watch is an expensive operation